# White Line appears on top of my page when I style a Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build the layout of my page, so far so good. Until I've placed a image on my header.

When I try styling the image, a white line appear on top of my page. I've place the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CCZjL/

When I remove the:

```
#header img {
    width:66px; 
    height:61px;
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
}
```

From my CSS file, the line is no longer there...???

Can anyone explain this to me?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your image is 61 px in height and 66 pixels in width? It might be stretched?

Comment: what if you add *{margin:0;padding:0;} http://jsfiddle.net/CCZjL/4/

Comment: It's actually a lot bigger, but event with the exact image size, or no image (as link on jsfiddle), I still get the white line on top?

Comment: By putting `position:absolute;` on the image, you remove it from content flow and cause the `h1` tag to become the top-most content in your header. Default browser styles put a `margin` on `h1`s, which bleeds out of your header container and pushes things down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `margin: 0;` and `line-height: 65px;` to `#header h1`

like so:

```
#header h1 {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 65px;
}
```

you can also remove `vertical-align: middle;` from `#header`.  It's not needed.

Comment: It is best to note that the `line-height` value should match the `height` of `#header` if you want the `h1` text to be centered.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I should have explained that. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

`white-space` is coming from `h1`.

Browser applies by default styles to elements.

It is better to remove all default styles. Like:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Write:

```
#header h1 {
   margin:0;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/CCZjL/5/)